# How to add content to files using Java

Tags: java, file-io, append

I have a result being entered into a file. This result is being done on a loop. So, every time a new result comes, it has to be appended into a file, but it is being overwritten. What should I use in order to append my results into a single file?

Comment: can I please see the error message? maybe even perhaps provide some code?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
BufferedWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename", true));
    out.write("aString");
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
finally{
    if(out != null){
        try{
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29),

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a
>   File object. If the second argument is
>   true, then bytes will be written to
>   the end of the file rather than the
>   beginning.

Answer (score 0):

here is the basic snippet

```
  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt",true);
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
  out.write("Hello Java 1");
  out.write("Hello Java 2");
```

**See Also**

- [FileWritter - Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Comment: Exception/resource handling  is left to you

Comment: @ALL  try{ TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();       Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(aNode);       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/deepu/korkin_lab/sample/testing.xml")); transformer.transform(source, result); }

Answer (score 0):

You should either keep the file open (sometimes it better, but usually not...) or open the output stream in [append mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```